# How do we configure conventions on Entity Framework 7?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core

Before EF7 I used the snipet below to remove conventions:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder builder)
{
      builder.Conventions.Remove<NavigationPropertyNameForeignKeyDiscoveryConvention>();
      builder.Conventions.Remove<PrimaryKeyNameForeignKeyDiscoveryConvention>();
      builder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
      builder.Conventions.Remove<PrimaryKeyNameForeignKeyDiscoveryConvention>();
      builder.Conventions.Remove<TypeNameForeignKeyDiscoveryConvention>();
}
```

How do we achieve the same result on Entity Framework 7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The API for conventions isn't currently stable. See https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2589.

It can be done, but it requires using dependency injection to override the internal workings of how `OnModelCreating` is called on your context. `DbContext` uses dependency injection to find an instance of `ModelSource` which provides the model builder (and the conventions).

To override the model source, add your own implementation into dependency injection:

```
    var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
    serviceCollection
        .AddEntityFramework()
        .AddSqlServer();
    serviceCollection.AddSingleton<SqlServerModelSource, MyModelSource>();
    var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

    using(var context = new MyContext(serviceProvider))
    {
        // ...
    }
```

Your implementation of `MyModelSource` should override `ModelSource.CreateConventionSet()`. See the [original source here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/7cbce2540ba667fa9451065c494e31113f6eca82/src/EntityFramework.Core/Internal/ModelSource.cs#L61)